# Cakephp - HABTM record won't delete with unique set to true

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1

CakePHP has the default of unique set to true, I've coded it just to make sure as well.
So I have the following DB structure:
Item HABTM Action, with unique set to true.

The situation is as followed:

Deletion works fine upon save when I delete 1 or more records, if ATLEAST 1 record stays 'alive'

Deletion doesn't work upon save when I delete all records ( or 1 record, if that's the only one). It simply keeps all existing records that way.

I've made sure with debug($this->request->data) right before save that it contained Nothing of Action.

Comment: Do you have the reverse association: Action HABTM Item? Where are you deleting from? You try to delete through a save operation (with nothing in the post for Action) or with Model::delete(), Model::deleteAll() ?

Comment: Yes, in both Models I have declared the HABTM relation with 'unique' set to true. I indeed try to delete through a save operation, with nothing in the post for Action. So I don't understand it, with nothing in the post for Action, it maintains the records, which it should not.

Comment: My suggestion is to ditch HABTM relationships and go with 'has many through' relationships.

Comment: I usually do that yes, since I often need a third column. But in this case, all I need is to couple to the two tables with their IDs, nothing more nothing less. But shouldn't it work like this? When I don't post any Action it should delete all existing data in the join table right? Yet it maintains the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the discussion in the comments on your post I am still confused, but what I understand is that you're trying to:
Save a POST in a format similar to this:
    array(
    'Item' => array(
        'id' => '3'
    )
With:

```
 $this->Item->SaveAll($this->request->data);
```

Your POST should contain a 'Action' key:

```
array(
    'Item' => array(
        'id' => '3'
    ),
    'Action' => array(
        'Action' => array()
    )
```

When the "Action" key is set, Cake knows that it has to go "over" the relation and to it's magic.
Then it will delete.

I just tested this on a App that I'm developing and actually found it to be a bug. :D The problem 
was that for the specific HATBM relation I had to use manually generated forms and thus when posting with nothing included the relation key was not set and the records, weren't deleted. I suppose that the Form Helper deals with this.

If you have a similar problem you can manage this in two different manners:

1. Put a hidden input with JavaScript
2. In the Controller check if the 'Action' key is set, and if not add it (as an empty array):

   $this->request->data['Action']['Action'] = array();

   This may be kind of intrusive, but It'll do the job.

Comment: Thanks! This works. I've added the `if(empty($this->request->data['modelname']))` check to my controller, and added an empty array as proposed, before saving. I am using the HTML form helper btw.

Comment: So if you're using the form helper than this might be a bug or impovemnt, you should consider reporting it: http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/